# How to delete duplicate files with similar name

Tags: powershell, file, duplicates, delete-file

I'm fairly new to PowerShell and I've not been able to find a definitive answer for my problem. I have a bunch of excel files in different folders which are duplicates but have varying file names due to them being updated. 
e.g. 
015 Approved warranty - Turkey - Case-2019 08-1437015 (issue 3),
015 Approved warranty - Turkey - Case-2019 08-1437015 (final issue)
015 Approved warranty - Turkey - Case-2019 08-1437015 
015 Approved warranty - Turkey - Case-2019 08-1437015 amended

I've tried different things but now I know the easiest way to filter the files but don't know the syntax. The anchor point will be the case number just after the date. I want to compare the case numbers against each other and only keep the newest ones (by date modified) and delete the rest. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
#take files from folder
$dupesource = 'C:\Users\W_Brooker\Documents\Destination\2019\08'

#filter files by case number (7 digit number after date)
$files = Get-ChildItem $dupesource -Filter "08-aaaaaaa"

#If case number is the same keep newest file delete rest
foreach ($file in $files){
$file | Delete-Item - sort -property Datemodified |select -Last 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PowerShell-idiomatic solution is to:

- combine multiple cmdlets in a single pipeline,
- in which `Group-Object` provides the core functionality of grouping duplicate files by shared case number in the file name:

```
# Define the regex that matches a case number:
# A 7-digit number embedded in filenames that duplicates share.
$regex = '\b\d{7}\b' 

# Enumerate all files and select only those whose name contains a case number.
Get-ChildItem -File $dupesource | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match $regex } | 
  # Group the resulting files by shared embedded case number.
  Group-Object -Property { [regex]::Match($_.BaseName, $regex).Value } |
    # Process each group:
    ForEach-Object {
      # In each group, sort files by most recently updated first.
      $_.Group | Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTimeUtc |
        # Skip the most recent file and delete the older ones.
        Select-Object -Skip 1 | Remove-Item -WhatIf
    }
```

<sup>The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) *previews* the operation. Remove it once you're sure it will do what you want.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\W_Brooker\Documents\Destination\2019\08' -Recurse

    # create datatable to store file Information in it

    $dt = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
    [void]$dt.Columns.Add('FileName',[string]::Empty.GetType() )
    [void]$dt.Columns.Add('CaseNumber',[string]::Empty.GetType() )
    [void]$dt.Columns.Add('FileTimeStamp',[DateTime]::MinValue.GetType() )
    [void]$dt.Columns.Add('DeleteFlag',[byte]::MinValue.GetType() )

    # Step 1: Make inventory

    foreach( $file in $files ) {

    if( !$file.PSIsContainer -and $file.Extension -like '.xls*' -and $file.Name -match '^.*\-\d+ *[\(\.].*$' ) {

        $row               = $dt.NewRow()
        $row.FileName      = $file.FullName
        $row.CaseNumber    = $file.Name -replace '^.*\-(\d+) *[\(\.].*$', '$1'
        $row.FileTimeStamp = $file.LastWriteTime
        $row.DeleteFlag    = 0

        [void]$dt.Rows.Add( $row )
    }
}

# Step 2: Mark files to delete

$rows = $dt.Select('', 'CaseNumber, FileTimeStamp DESC')

$caseNumber = ''

foreach( $row in $rows ) {
    if( $row.CaseNumber -ne $caseNumber ) {
        $caseNumber = $row.CaseNumber
        Continue
    }
    $row.DeleteFlag = 1
    [void]$dt.AcceptChanges()
}

# Step 3: Delete files

$rows = $dt.Select('DeleteFlag = 1', 'FileTimeStamp DESC')

foreach( $row in $rows ) {
    $fileName = $row.FileName
    Remove-Item -Path $fileName -Force | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: Has the case number always 7 digits? In this case, the solution would be easier.

Comment: Yeah the case number is always 7 digits. That's the only part that is consistent in length and it's position is always after the date e.g Case 2019 08-DDDDDDD.

Comment: Good to know that the solution works, but there's no good reason to use `System.Data.DataTable`, because PowerShell's `Group-Object` and `Sort-Object` cmdlets enable a conceptually simpler and much more concise solution.
As an aside: Instead of something like `[string]::Empty.GetType()`, use the type literal directly: `[string]`

Comment: @mklement0 I have a C++/C# history and I love clear structures and a step-by-step approach. Nested pipes are more "powershellish", but are difficult to read and understand later on.

Comment: While understandably unfamiliar at first, pipelines too are step-by-step solutions, and they allow you to operate on a higher level of abstraction, which ultimately also help readability (with enough familiarity).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that leverages the PowerShell Group-Object cmdlet.

It uses a regex to matche files on the case number, ignoring those that don't have a case number. See the screen shot at the bottom that shows test data (a collection of test xlsx files)

```
cls

#Assume that each file has an xlsx extension.
#Assume that a case number always looks like this: "Case-YYYY~XX-Z" where YYYY is 4 digits, ~ is a single space, XX is two digits, and Z is one-to-many-digits

#make a list of xlsx files (recursive)
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath .\ExcelFiles -Recurse -Include *.xlsx 

#$file is a System.IO.FileInfo object. Parse out the Case number and add it to the $file object as CaseNumber property
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $Matches = $null

    $file.Name -match "(^.*)(Case-\d{4}\s{1}\d{2}-\d{1,})(.*\.xlsx$)" | out-null

    if ($Matches.Count -eq 4)
    {
        $caseNumber = $Matches[2]
        $file | Add-Member -NotePropertyName CaseNumber -NotePropertyValue $caseNumber
    }
    Else
    {
        #child folders will end up in this group too
        $file | Add-Member -NotePropertyName CaseNumber -NotePropertyValue "NoCaseNumber"
    }
}

#group the files by CaseNumber
$files | Group-Object -Property CaseNumber -OutVariable fileGroups | out-null

foreach ($fileGroup in $fileGroups)
{
    #skip folders and files that don't have a valid case #
    if ($fileGroup.Name -eq "NoCaseNumber")
    {
        continue
    }

    #for each group: sort files descending by LastWriteTime. Newest file will be first, so skip 1st file and remove the rest
    $fileGroup.Group | sort -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -skip 1 | foreach {Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Force}
}
```

**Test Data**

[image]